# Forward port on localhost to some remote host:port

Tags: port-forwarding

Suppose there is some server running on remotehost.some.where:4444. I have a software that insists to connect to localhost:5555. I can forward this with `ssh` as

```
ssh -L 5555:remotehost.some.where:4444 myuser@localhost
```

But this requires an unnecessary ssh connection to localhost, which the addition of `-N` would not prevent. How can I do this port forwarding without the login, possibly with another tool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest solution is to run some sort of TCP proxy. You can use `socat`, for example:

```
socat tcp-listen:5555,bind=127.0.0.1,fork tcp:remotehost.some.where:4444
```

While this is running, connections to port `5555` on your local host will be forwarded to port `4444` on `remotehost.some.where`.

The command I'm using here only listens on `127.0.0.1`. If you actually want to accept connections from other hosts on port `5555`, you can drop the `bind=127.0.0.1` option.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of doing that.

1) If you're GNU/Linux, just use `iptables` to do so;

2) If you really, really, REALLY wanna use SSH, generate a RSA keypair, copy it to your ~./ssh/authorized_keys file and repeat your command, adding the `-N` option.

3) If you're using a Debian, or Debian-based distribution, you can use `redir`.

4) You can accomplish that also using `socat`, like this:

`socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,fork TCP4:www.yourdomain.org:8080`

Hope that helps.

Comment: (1) not so useful without an example (and performing nat when `localhost` is involved can be tricky), (2) the OP explicitly doesn't want to use ssh, (3) sure, (4) that's what I said.

Comment: 1) There are plenty examples on the Internet; 2) The OP didn't said that; 4) I've finished my answer without seeing yours. After I saw it, I upvoted your answer.